# GWT - Using a java bean parameter directly in a native method

Tags: java, gwt

I am trying to create an object in plain java to pass it to a js library directly (as an anonymous object) using a native method, but the library doesn't seem to "see" its fields.

For example, let's say the library has a method that is normally initialized like this:

```
mylibrary.initializeApp({
    appId: "myappid",
    name: "test name"}
);
```

I want to create a native GWT method that has a parameter a class created in java.

For example, I want to create a class named Config (the library does not have a Config class in javascript):

```
public class Config {
    public String appId;
    public String name;
}
```

And a method to initialize the library:

```
public static native void initializeApp(Config config) /*-{
        console.log(config);
        $wnd.mylibrary.initializeApp(config); 
}-*/;
```

How can I do this using JS overlay / jsinterop or JSON object utils? (I am trying to create a simple Firebase wrapper for messaging, and I would like to do it as simple as possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using JsInterop, create your Config class thus:

```
import jsinterop.annotations.JsPackage;
import jsinterop.annotations.JsType;

@JsType(isNative=true, namespace=JsPackage.GLOBAL, name="Object")
public class Config {
    public String appId;
    public String name;
}
```

Instantiate an object of `Config`, which will be an anonymous native object that you can pass to the library as you are already doing in your `initializeApp` method (which is using a JSNI overlay)